# How to connect the video tag that fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made project about video stream, but I have a question.
I want to connect the .ts Stream to video tag in Html on Set-Top box.
but It isn't the full screen.

```
<html style="width:960px; height:540px;">

... javascript, style ...

<body bgcolor="#000000" style="width:960px; height:540px;overflow:hidden...">
   <div style="width:960px; height:540px;">
        <video style="width:960px; height:540px;" preload="true" autoplay="true" src="udp://.../" type="video/ogg"></video>
   </div>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

It appear the black gap with screen. How to solve this problem that disable gap?
Thanks any reply.

Comment: I'm not sure but is that the correct way of displaying a video? look at this. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: put your code in fiddle.

Comment: Do u have Video server running on UDP port as written at your code? src="udp://.../" type="video/ogg
Can you play video with VLC?

Comment: Yes, I play video with VLC.